# Get Value Only From Multidemensional Code after a csv parse

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have been trying to get the value of my combined rate, but running into some trouble with simply getting the value :

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [ZipCode] => 01014 [CombinedRate] => 0.0625 ) )  <--- this is the array that is printed.
```

Here is the full code:

```
<?php
function csv_to_array($filename= '', $delimiter=',')
{
if(!file_exists($filename) || !is_readable($filename))
    return FALSE;

$header = NULL;
$data = array();
if (($handle = fopen($filename, 'r')) !== FALSE)
{
    while (($row = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, $delimiter)) !== FALSE)
    {
        if(!$header)
            $header = $row;
        else
            $data[] = array_combine($header, $row);
    }
    fclose($handle);
}
return $data;
}


$zipsearch = csv_to_array($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/textfiles/taxes.csv');

function search($array, $key, $value)
{
$results = array();

if (is_array($array)) {
    if (isset($array[$key]) && $array[$key] == $value) {
        $results[] = $array;
    }

    foreach ($array as $subarray) {
        $results = array_merge($results, search($subarray, $key, $value));
    }
}

return $results;
}

$valueofzip = search( $zipsearch, 'ZipCode', '01014');


print_r($valueofzip)
/*
Need Code To print Just value of that array
*/

?>
```

I just need the value of the combined rate after the zipcode is found from the array that is printed, but for whatever reason I am just missing it,

How do I just get the value of "Combined Rate" from this array that is printed : Array ( [0] => Array ( [ZipCode] => 01014 [CombinedRate] => 0.0625 ) )

Essentially this page will print out a single tax rate

Comment: I figured it out : I figured it out, Dumb Mistake on my part but hopefully this helps someone in the future.  This was the for loop I used : 

    foreach($valueofzip as $key => $values) {
    print $values['CombinedRate'];
    }

Comment: If there's only one element in the top level array, you don't need a loop. You could just do `$valueofzip[0]['CombinedRate']`

Comment: ahhh that would make sense as well, leave it to me to find the complicated way to accomplish a simple task haha

Comment: I have posted up an answer so that you can mark the question as solved. Hopefully you find it useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the value that you are trying to retrieve is simply:

```
$valueofzip[0]['CombinedRate']
```

i.e. the value with the key "CombinedRate" in the zeroth element of `$valueofzip`.

If you are anticipating there being more than one array returned by your `search` function, then a `foreach` loop would be more appropriate:

```
foreach($valueofzip as $zip) {
   if (isset($zip['CombinedRate'])) echo $zip['CombinedRate'];
}
```

Depending on exactly what you want to do with the value, you might also want to take a look at `array_walk`, `array_map`, etc. in the documentation. They can be used to traverse the array and apply a callback function to each element. For example:

```
$valueofzip = array(array("ZipCode" => 01014, "CombinedRate" => 0.0625),
                    array("ZipCode" => 02025, "CombinedRate" => 0.125 ));

$combined_rates = array_map(function($x) { if (isset($x['CombinedRate'])) return $x['CombinedRate']; }, $valueofzip));
print_r($combined_rates);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 0.0625
    [1] => 0.125
)
```

Comment: I approved the answer as this will help other people in the future as well, thanks Tom for a well thought out answer, much appreciated